# Transferring Data Between Interface Builder Instantiated Classes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, class

I'm writing a simple Cocoa application that takes some file URLs (via drag-and-drop), and then does stuff with those files. I have a class (subclass of NSView) that controls the drag-and-drop mechanism, and is assigned to an NSView via Interface Builder (using the "Custom Class" option). The file URLs go into an NSMutableArray.

I then have another class that should take those file URLs and do some stuff with them. This class also has an IBAction connected to a NSButton that calls the 'do stuff' method.

My question is, how can I, and what is considered the best way, to get the data from the NSMutableArray (or the array it self) from the 'drag-and-drop' class, to the 'do stuff' class. I am aware of concepts like Key Value Coding, Bindings, and Core Data, however I am unfamiliar with them and don't want to learn one and realise it doesn't suit my needs.

Any help with what I should do here, and how I should get started would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If your app is dealing with just one (or very few) arrays, you can easily write them to NSUserDefaults in one class and then retrieve them from the other class. Once retrieved, you can change it how you like and write it back to NSUserDefaults. This has the added benefit of persisting your data on the device from one session to another. Some might say this is overkill, but for small amounts of data, it works very nicely.

write to NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//Change this line depending on object you arr saving (eg Array)
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstHome"];

[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

get from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//Change this line depending on object you are saving (eg Array)
BOOL tempBOOL = [standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"firstHome"];
```

There are definitely other options, but something like CoreData is overkill for just one array of links.